# Matching nodes that have relationships exclusively with specific nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking to return a list of nodes that require only the same tools as other specific jobs.

My nodes are jobs, the jobs have a require relationship with tools which are also nodes.

If I match a specific job, e.g building a shed and building a shed requires a hammer, a screwdriver and a saw. What other jobs require only tools required when building a shed (including jobs requiring any combination of those tools or even just one as long as that job requires no other tools) For example building a fence requires the hammer and saw and thus should be returned but dismantling a shed should not be returned even though it requires the hammer, because it also requires a crowbar.

Right now I have

```
Match (j:Job{Title: 'Build Shed'}) - [:Requires] -> (t:tools)
Match (o:otherJob) - [:Requires] -> (t)
return j,o,t
```

But this returns all jobs that require any of those tools even if those jobs also require other tools that aren't required to build the shed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to review the Cypher knowledge base entry for [performing match intersection](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/).

That said, the article will help you to find jobs that require all of the tools you matched to previously, but you'll need to perform just a bit more work to ensure that the number of tools required by the job is exactly the number of tools you're working with.

Here's an example, using the first approach to count the number of matches when expanding from tools to jobs that require them:

```
MATCH (j:Job{Title: 'Build Shed'}) - [:Requires] -> (t:tools)
WITH collect(t) as tools, count(t) as requiredToolCount
UNWIND tools as t // change back to rows
MATCH (o:otherJob) - [:Requires] -> (t)
WITH o, tools, requiredToolCount, count(t) as toolsRequired
WHERE toolsRequired = requiredToolCount AND toolsRequired = size((o)-[:REQUIRES]->())
RETURN o, tools
```

The idea here is that we collect the required tools and get their count (so for your example: hammer, screwdriver, and saw, so that's a count of 3 required tools.

Then we unwind the collection back to rows, and expand out from the tool to jobs that require that tool. We then aggregate, so for each of those jobs, we get the count of those 3 tools that matched to the job. We only want to keep the jobs where the number of those tools that matched = the required number of tools, so for this example case, we only want to keep jobs that got a count of 3 matches (1 per each of those tools).

Lastly we check the total number of required tools for the job, and make sure that equals the number of tools we're interested in (since if it's more, then that job requires more tools than the ones we're considering.

EDIT

With the additional requirement, we want to also find jobs that may use less than the total number of tools we matched to from the starting job, but only if no additional tools are needed. Here's how we can modify the query:

```
MATCH (j:Job{Title: 'Build Shed'}) - [:Requires] -> (t:tools)
WITH collect(t) as tools, count(t) as maxRequiredToolCount
UNWIND tools as t // change back to rows
MATCH (o:otherJob) - [:Requires] -> (t)
WITH o, tools, maxRequiredToolCount, count(t) as toolsRequired
WHERE toolsRequired <= maxRequiredToolCount AND toolsRequired = size((o)-[:REQUIRES]->())
RETURN o, tools
```

Comment: Thank you, I had read the article on match intersection, but couldn't get it to work for this use case. Could your solution also work for jobs requiring say just the hammer and the saw? As long as those were the only tools that were required?

Comment: I added on to my answer with a query that should work here.